# GIT Hub using different accounts to push

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2015, user-accounts

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with GIT Hub extension. I created an account on GIT hub using my personal email (GITemail@somedomain.com). When I see the push records from Visual Studio, it is using my other email (MyMailAccount@anotherdoamin.com) which I use for Office products. This account has nothing to do with GIT or GITHUB or VS or anything else which could be related to this action. There are no issues with the push itself but I am surprised that GIT is using a completely unrelated account to push code.

Is there a way to ensure that GIT does not use any other account of mine to do any of its actions?

Update:

1. I created account on GIT hub website using mygitemail@somedomain.com
2. I opened VS 2015 (not signed in) and downloaded the extension for GIT HUB
3. I used Team -> Manage connections to connect to source control.
4. Connect to GIT HUB using same username and password as I did on GIT HUB website.
5. Created a new solution, committed and pushed it.
6. Push was done using name and email same as the one I use in outlook which is myoutlookemail@anotherdomain.com. And has nothing to do with GIT
7. In visual studio's team explorer, I see the name I use in outlook and on mouse hover I see the email I set up in outlook.
8. In GIT Hub's web dashboard, I see under commit history the name I use in outlook and nothing else. No collaborators, nothing. This name was not explicitly made known to GIT HUB.

Comment: Do not confuse your GitHub account username with Git user name and email. They are unrelated.

Comment: I am not confusing those. I have a repository on GIT Hub with an account on GIT Hub. When I commit from VS, it takes my email account which has nothing to do with GIT.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are seeing and where? I'd expect at least three independent places where some kind of user ID is used in this scenario...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I updated the question with steps I did

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the settings page under GIT HUB extension which had sneakily picked up my Windows details. I corrected it now and hopefully that will work.

P.S. How do I close the question for answers now?

Comment: You can accept your answer as the correct one.